# How can I connect to Postgres using JayDeBeApi? It doesn't find the org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, jaydebeapi

I have to connect to a DB2 to extract some data and create a Tableau Data Extract, in order to do this I wanted to use JayDeBeApi, and to test it I was trying to connect myself to a small Postgres database, but I can't establish a proper connection to it because it throws me all the time the following error:

`jpype._jexception.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class org.postgresql.Driver not found`

My current implementation is this

```py
import jaydebeapi as jdbc

sql = 'Select * From world.city'
postgresql_class = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
postgresql_jdbc_path = 'path/to/postgresql-42.2.4.jar'
postgresql_url = 'jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database'
postgresql_user = 'user'
postgresql_pw = 'pass'

conn = jdbc.connect(postgresql_class, 
                    [postgresql_url, postgresql_user, postgresql_pw], 
                    postgresql_jdbc_path)

curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute('SELECT * FROM csv_reports LIMIT 2')
curs.fetchall()
curs.close()
conn.close()
```

Does anyone know what class do I have to specify in order to make this work? Or how do i have to specify the jdbc path so that JayDeBeApi can use the class or something

Comment: Perhaps try `postgresql_jdbc_path = ['path/to/postgresql-42.2.4.jar']`

Comment: Also, I don't think that `postgresql_url` should be in the list with the username and password. More like `jdbc.connect(postgresql_class, postgresql_url, [postgresql_user, postgresql_pw], postgresql_jdbc_path)`

Comment: The listing ```postgresql_url``` was the problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JayDeBeApi documentation](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi#usage)

> The first argument to `connect` is the name of the Java driver class. The second argument is a string with the JDBC connection URL. Third you can optionally supply a sequence consisting of user and password or alternatively a dictionary containing arguments that are internally passed as properties to the Java `DriverManager.getConnection` method. See the Javadoc of `DriverManager` class for details.

So you shouldn't be including the connection URL in the list with the username and password; it should be on its own as the second argument:

```python
jdbc.connect(postgresql_class, 
             postgresql_url, 
             [postgresql_user, postgresql_pw], 
             postgresql_jdbc_path)
```